# Mock de uma classe que tem paramêtros no construtor

Tags: java, mockito

```
public class ParseProcessoTest {
private final String PATTERN_DATA_HORA = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
JSONObject jsonObject;

@Mock
ParseProcesso parseProcesso;

@Before
public void init(){
    jsonObject = new JSONObject("string qualquer");
    when(parseProcesso.movimentacaoTemAnexo(new JSONObject("outra string"))).thenReturn(false);
}

@Test
public void testaParse() throws IOException {
    ParseProcesso parseProcesso = new ParseProcesso(jsonObject);
    Processo processoTeste = parseProcesso.parse();

    //demais métodos
```

A classe `ParseProcesso` recebe em seu construtor um `jsonObject` como parâmetro. 
Não há como instanciar uma classe mockada, então o `when` lança uma exceção. 
O teste cria uma instância da classe `ParseProcesso` (mas obviamente não dá certo)... Alguém tem alguma ideia do que fazer?

Comment: Não dá pra usar `new ParseProcesso(any());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Utilização do [@Spy / Mockito.spy()](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Spy.html)

Ex:

Construtor com parâmetro:

```
public class MyService {

  private String param;

  public MyService(String anyParam) {
    this.param = anyParam;
  }

  public String getParam() {
    return param;
  }

}
```

Teste:

```
public class MyServiceTest {

  private String DEFAULT_STRING_VALUE = "any";

  @Test
  public void classInstanceShouldNotBeNull() {
    MyService service = Mockito.spy(new MyService("doesNotMatter"));
    Assert.assertNotNull(service);
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldReturnMyMockedString() {
    MyService service = Mockito.spy(new MyService("doesNotMatter"));
    Mockito.when(service.getParam()).thenReturn(DEFAULT_STRING_VALUE);
    Assert.assertEquals(DEFAULT_STRING_VALUE, service.getParam());
  }
}
```

2 - Utilização da extensão Mockito do [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock)

Você poderia utilizar o método [PoweMockito.whenNew()](http://javadox.com/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.4.9/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#whenNew(java.lang.Class)) pra retornar seu mock toda vez que uma nova instância da sua classe for criada:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(MyService.class).withArguments(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(myMock);
```

3 - Refatorar seu código para utilização de Factory (talvez [isso](https://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/01/mock-constructor/) te ajude com alguma outra ideia).